# A: Swapping in Paging (memory allocation)

Tags: linux, memory-management, process, linux-kernel, paging

During a course of Operative System, our professor said

> "when a page is no more necessary to be in the RAM it's taken in the swap-area of the memory. The Swap area is called like this for historical reasons, because it was used in a process called swapping, which involves the swap of a whole process. Indeed now we are taking in memory only one page, not an entire process."

Is this correct? i can't find it anywhere online!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is quite correct, apart one (or two) things: a page gets swapped out when there is need for more RAM, not when the page is no more needed. When is no more needed, a page is freed.

About the "swap" term: it is true that it is a historical name, but nevertheless it is still correct to say "swap", because pages are swapped from and to the "swap area".

Finally: a whole process *can* reside in RAM, or even just a few pages of it (or none at all!). It depends on how much RAM is free, and how the operating system allocates the available memory. See for example the linux `swappiness`: it's a simple control to tell the kernel how it must treat RAM and swap space.